# TinyMCE: Looking for line count solution

Tags: javascript, html, editor, tinymce

I am looking for a plugin or code with a functionality like the "line count" or "line number" in common editors.
The line number usually is shown on the left border of the editors content.
Anyone got an idea how to do it with TinyMCE?

Example:

line number | content

1. line number one
2. number two
   3.
3. one line skipped (three is empty)
   5.
4. contents end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using a special stylesheet containing a png with the numbers from 1 to 999 placed on the left side of the editors iframe. Important is here that this solution only works for a predefined font size and line-height!

```
body {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  background-image:url("http://www.mydomain.com/images/editor_lines.png") !important;
  background-repeat:repeat-y !important;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  line-height: 19px;
  margin: 1px 0 0;
  padding-left: 40px !important;  /*space for the png*/
}
```

Comment: Your image is present.. please update your code

Answer (score 2):

Here is a character count from http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=10581

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ....

     //Character count
     theme_advanced_path : false,
     setup : function(ed) {
          ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) {   
               var strip = (tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()).replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
               var text = strip.split(' ').length + " Words, " +  strip.length + " Characters"
        tinymce.DOM.setHTML(tinymce.DOM.get(tinyMCE.activeEditor.id + '_path_row'), text);   
    });
     }

});
```

You could modify this to look for the line breaks `/n,<br>,etc...`

Comment: Well, this is not what i was looking for. Important here is that the numbers have to be directly in front of the lines. I will post my solution as answer.